# how to call C#(aspx.cs) function by using java script/Jquery by passing parameters

Tags: c#, javascript, methods, call, using

```
.aspx
 -----------------------

    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    >>      $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".cssBtns").click(function () {
                    // call aspx.cs method generateInfo(this.id,this.className)
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>

.aspx.cs
-----------------------

    public void generateInfo(int btnId, string className){

         print:// css button id:---
                  css button class:----
    }
```

> > how can i call generateInfo method which is aspx.cs page by using java script/JQuery. and which is the best way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call an ASP.NET c# method using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089760/how-to-call-an-asp-net-c-sharp-method-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.ajax()`, `$.post()`, `$.get()` or `$.getJSON()` for doing this.

```
$(".cssBtns").click(function () {
     $.ajax({
        url : 'aspx function path here'
     });
});
```

See the link below for more reference.

[how to call an ASP.NET c# method using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089760/how-to-call-an-asp-net-c-sharp-method-using-javascript)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: This is a really weak answer to the question, doesn't show handling of parameters (one of the main components of the query) and doesn't even provide reference links.

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar, Only static method you can call by this. but i wanna call non static method.

Comment: @prasobkumarkp no you can call dynamic functions too but for that you need to code that way....if i know asp.net then i would have helped you but i do not know asp.net so i don't know how it works.