# how to call C# function with javascript in .NET ?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically Im following the tutorial from:

[how to call an ASP.NET c# method using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089760/how-to-call-an-asp-net-c-sharp-method-using-javascript)

this code will create a userform and prompt the user to enter name and password.

I created  a webform called Default.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <fieldset style="width: 200px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmailAddress" runat="server" Text="Email Address"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </fieldset>
        <div>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnCreateAccount" runat="server" Text="Signup" OnClientClick="Signup();return false;" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Signup() {
        var email = document.getElementById('<%=txtEmail.ClientID %>').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('<%=txtPassword.ClientID %>').value;

        PageMethods.RegisterUser(email, password, onSucess, onError);

        function onSucess(result) {
            alert(result);
        }

        function onError(result) {
            alert('Cannot process your request at the moment, please try later.');
        }
    }
</script>
```

and under Default.aspx.cs I have

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace email1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {

        [WebMethod]
public static string RegisterUser(string email, string password)
{
    string result = "Congratulations!!! your account has been created.";
    if (email.Length == 0)//Zero length check
    {
        result = "Email Address cannot be blank";
    }
    else if (!email.Contains(".") || !email.Contains("@")) //some other basic checks
    {
        result = "Not a valid email address";
    }
    else if (!email.Contains(".") || !email.Contains("@")) //some other basic checks
    {
        result = "Not a valid email address";
    }

    else if (password.Length == 0)
    {
        result = "Password cannot be blank";
    }
    else if (password.Length < 5)
    {
        result = "Password canonot be less than 5 chars";
    }

    return result;
}


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what's the prob in it?

Comment: What is not working? Did you check for any JavaScript error?

Comment: What is your Question?