# calling code behind function using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a javascript function for ShowDocument in which I need to call a code behind function
My Js FUNCTION is as follows:

```
function showDocument(_id) 
{
    PageMethods.ShowDocument();
}
```

Codebehind:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void ShowDocument()
{
    byte[] bytes;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Data FROM FileUploader2", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    bytes = (byte[])reader["Data"];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have added EnablePageMethods= true in my aspx as well.

But when I debug, it triggers my ShowDocument function but does not go inside my code behind function. It just skips it. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean you want to call your `web method` from `JavaScript function`? what's your back end method `URL`

Comment: Yes I want to call my c# from javascript.  For which I followed this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089760/how-to-call-an-asp-net-c-sharp-method-using-javascript .My function gets trigerred as well but then it skips to the end.

Comment: Make sure you have specified the ScriptManage Id.

Comment: I have added this at the top of aspx <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>  where do I have to specify ID="ScriptManager1"  ?